# What is the proper way to create an URL and add parameters?

Tags: java, url, uri

I have been working with java.net.URL class and I'm at the point where I need to add parameters to the URL object variable. I have seen many ways to add parameters such as string concatenation or creating new URL objects and passing the wanted parameters to the URL class constructor. But I have also seen UriBuilder and other ways to create URLs or URIs and later add parameters to them. What is the proper way to construct a URL in java to later add parameters?

The lazy way I've been doing it is as follow:

```
String url = "http://www.site.com/";
url += "?";
url += "param1=" + 1;
url += "&";
url += "param2=" + 2;

URL url = new URL(url);
```

Is that the best way to add parameters to an URL? is there a better way?

Thanks,
Y_Y

Comment: Third party libraries do it better. You'll want to url encode things as well.

Comment: Also, you're missing a `&` between params. That's the kind of thing 3rd party libs do better. They are tried and tested. Check out `spring-web`, which might be overkill, but provides a good `UriComponentsBuilder` class for this.

Comment: That's true, I just edited the error. I will check out some third parties. Any links you can provide?

Comment: [`UriComponentsBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard form using URL in java

```
URL(URL baseURL, String relativeURL)

String baseURL= "http://www.site.com/";
```

Form the relativeURL using the StringBuilder or String based on your parameters.

Other way is to go for Third Party LIB.

Answer (score 1):

If your don't have any restrictions on using an external library, I suggest adding [Apache HttpClient](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3)

Below is an example:

```
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("http://google.com/search");
    builder.addParameter("q","web apps");
    System.out.println(builder.build().toString()); //outputs http://google.com/search?q=web+apps
```